# increment a loop by power of 2

Tags: c++

I know this is a very simple thing but I cant figure out how to increment the loop by powers of two. The program is comparing insertion sort and merge sort and n should increment in powers of ie 2, 4, 8, 16, 32.... This is what I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int a,n,b;
    double mergesort;
    double insertionsort;

    cout << "Enter a and b values ";
    cin >> a >> b;

    do
    {
        for(n=2; n=pow(n,++);
        {
        insertionsort = a*pow(n,2);
        mergesort = b*n*log2(n);
        }

        cout <<"insertion sort= " << insertionsort << "merge sort= " <<mergesort;
        cout <<"n" << n;

    }while(insertionsort < mergesort);

    cout << "Value of n that insertion beat merge sort is " << " n ";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This loop will increase `n` by a power of 2 each iteration up to some `n_max`:

```
for (int n = 2; n <= n_max; n *= 2) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work, the calculations were not right

Comment: @josh Well you have a mistake elsewhere then as the loop I provided definitely will proceed in the sequence you require (2,4,8,16,...)

Comment: yeah sorry you are right its correct, the problem is I how to implement it for it to stop when insertion sort is less than merge sort.

Comment: @josh Add a simple condition such as `if (insertionsort < mergesort) {break;}` in the loop to stop iterating when insertionsort value is less than mergesort value

Comment: I have tried doing that but it stops after iterating once